# Possible to generate an XML file from specific divs?

Tags: android, xml

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLhWp.jpg

Basically, from the image above. I would like to know if it is at all possible to generate an XML file to get the information from those specific div classes.

If so, a link to a tutorial would be great, I haven't found anything that I think is useful from some googling.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to any of the following:

http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Also you can try to use:
Html.fromHtml(source) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

Comment: Another great library for this purpose: http://jsoup.org/. Please vote up if you satisfied with the answer